# Calling an insert values using statement with in another stored procedure dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am creating a stored procedure within a stored procedure and am looking to insert dynamically generated values within a stored procedure to another stored procedure, I tried going to many places but still not find out my answer or they are not near to my given scenario please check below

Below 6 lines are part of above stored procedure and based on these six lines I would like to create another stored procedure where I am calling them for insert statement these six lines are doing the job I wanted but how to print those or call them within a stored procedure so that it shows the insert statement.

I tried output and table variable still not able to populate the insert statement. Please help me achieve this thanks

```
declare @DD varchar(max)

set @DD='select '+isnull(@allcol,'')+ ' from '+@Table1+' a '+'inner join '+@Table2+' b on a.'+@KeyColumn1+'=b.'+@KeyColumn2+isnull(' inner join '+@Table3+' c on a.'+@KeyColumn1+'=c.'+@KeyColumn3,'') 
--print @DD
--exec (@DD)

-- Declare your stored procedure name here
DECLARE @create_stored_procedure nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max)

-- Please provide name to your stored procedure
set @TableName = 'staging_ABC'

SET @create_stored_procedure = N' 
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_' + @TableName + ']
   AS
   BEGIN
    -- If stage table exist drop it and then insert into [staging_ABC]
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE NAME = ''' + @TableName + ''')
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Staging_ABC]
    END

    -- We need to populate insert statement here from @dd
    --print @DD
  END '
```

Comment: http://XYproblem.info - what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Please clearify what you mean by "populate insert statement"

Comment: I am trying to create a store proc within a store proc and trying to populate select statement generated dynamically in it

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're looking to create the stored procedure? As opposed to creating the insert statement in a variable, and then executing that variable? (`declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from dbo.table_name' exec(@sql);`)